# Jungle or Lane when lasthitskill is good?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am currently at 1100 elo and would like to get the next 100 points up to 1200 elo. 
I can lasthit reasonably good, mostly leading in cs in the early/mid stages of the game. 
I notice that most of the times my team does not have a jungler, and that having one is a real advantage over the enemy team.

My question is: Should i switch to a jungler so that we have one, even if it means missing out on farm for my team? What soft skills do i need as a jungler, e.g what should i pay most attention to when going into the jungle?

Probably another question, but what else can i do to carry harder? I mostly only lasthit and that means playing safe and not getting many kills mid in favor of harass.

cheers

Comment: There are not many junglers in elo hello 1000-1200 but there are even less good tanks or also offtanks(cc). Many players prefer to take "the evil killers/carries that pwn other champions and call them noobs" or at least this is what they hope. In reality it happens often that in those cases team average is too squishy and in mid-late game they fail because ad/ap carries miss the protection from tanks/offtanks(cc). So try to take a good tank, maybe you can jump out of elo hell. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is: Should i switch to a
>   jungler so that we have one, even if
>   it means missing out on farm for my
>   team?

Depends on the draft pick order, if you are a good jungler and you are first pick, you can pick one immediately; if you are not first pick and notice the enemy team has already picked a jungler, you can ask in chat if anyone is jungling. If not, it is recommended that your team has a jungler as well, then top lane will be 1v1, you can control the Dragon on bottom lane, and you can set up ganks.

> What soft skills do i need as a
>   jungler, e.g what should i pay most
>   attention to when going into the
>   jungle?

You need all of these amongst others:

1. Map awareness: Control (a.k.a) warding the river sides during early game usually after your first blue pill, doing so will prevent your bottom and top lanes of being ganked. Warding strategic places during mid/late game can win fights, baron and some of the enemy jungle bushes or even your own jungle bushes.
2. Wise use of Smite: If you are going to jungle, you should almost always have smite summoner spell with you (very few exceptions here, perhaps Nunu), it will make your jungling faster and you can also kill Dragon/Baron faster having the possibility of kill stealing if you are aware of the enemy team killing them.
3. Lane awareness: One of the most important things a jungler should do is besides killing the neutral creeps and roaming around, is setting up ganks / denying / defending turrets; whenever you see any lane is being outpushed you must leave jungle and defend the turret while the laner pills back, also harassing mid, by just making the enemy mid laner blue pill back will make your mid lane gain more exp/gold by killing creeps alone.

> Probably another question, but what
>   else can i do to carry harder? I
>   mostly only lasthit and that means
>   playing safe and not getting many
>   kills mid in favor of harass.

Last hit is a very important thing to do overall, not only carries should do it, however you can easily harass while last hitting, it just takes a little bit of practice and knowing exactly what your champion skills are. In order to effetively carry, you should just play smart and aggresive when possible during team fights and laning phase, meaning letting your tanks engage and start the fights, targeting the enemy AD/AP carries. Also a very importing thing a carry should do is pick items accordingly to what the enemy team comp is, perhaps maybe just stacking AP flat items would not be the greatest idea if the enemy team is heavy on MR, stacking AP + Magic Pen items would do much better, same idea applies to AD carries; additionally if you as carry are having a good early/mid game, you should also buy some defensive items, such as Guardian Angel / Banshees Veil in order to have a little more survivability.

Useful links:

- [Stonewall Jungle Mindsets](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=418185&highlight=stonewall), check out especially *Warwick's* mindset, it answers your first 2 questions in a pretty good and clear way.
- [Delepitore's Comprehensive Guide](http://leaguecraft.com/strategies/gameguide/145-delepitore-s-comprehensive-guide-improvement-101.xhtml)

Comment: +1 for the amount of work you put into the answer. I am not a very good jungler, doing much much better in lane, bc of lasthitting (comes from dota i guess xD). Does the fact that our jungle is used provide enough advantage over a non-jungling team, that i should just try jungling?

Comment: Fiddle NEEDS smite now fyi, but overall very nice answer.

Comment: @tarrasch One team having a jungler over the other who does not provides exp/gold advantage to the top laner and gives the aforementioned advantages on my post, it is definately worth it guaranteed top lane wont outpush and wont die in a silly way; additionally it would be worth it if the champion you select is a good natural jungler. @danixd well this is still a bit controversial, I know fiddle's drain heal was nerfed but not its damage hence he can still jungle very fast, I used to jungle w/o smite on him with just a doran ring, but now instead I would pick a Cloth Armor + 5 pots

Comment: I would say that taking Smite is always a must. Even with Nunu's Consume, Smite helps you tear through the jungle uber fast and always has utility during the game, especially when finishing off dragon or baron. Don't be on the stupid team that makes [this mistake](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu2lF1I059k) of not taking smite. You will get trolololled.

Comment: so i wil try going tank/jungle. normally i would only play hardcarries, but i had enough money to buy some wards too. But i could also try nunu i guess. hes a tank, has cc and jungles

Comment: If you want to tank & jungle, try the following champions: _Nunu_, _Amumu_, _Cho Gath_, _Malphite_, _Rammus_, _Alistar_, the list its in descending order of Jungling power in my opinion (By jungling merely meaning ability to clear the jungle in the less time possible)

Comment: Stonewalls mindset videos were removed from youtube :(